# Titanium Appcelerator Ti Media Picker widget

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am trying to use the widget https://github.com/appcelerator-forks/gimdongwoo.ti-media-picker-widget

But I am receiving the error:
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: ti.mediapicker for architecture: x86_64

I follow the instructions, but it is not working for me.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a widget you need to look at the actual module that is used. In this case it is: https://github.com/gimdongwoo/TiMediaPicker and the iOS version is 3 years old (Ti SDK 3.5.0) and needs to be recompiled. So you need to download the repo (https://github.com/gimdongwoo/TiMediaPicker) and compile the module for iOS with the latest SDK. Details here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Quick_Start